# How to compile programs involving external libraries using MSVC developer command prompt?

Tags: c++

I am working on an opengl project (in Visual Studio 2019) in which I am using glfw and glad. I want to create a makefile (windows platform) so that other team members could also compile and execute it. I am using nmake command on the developer command prompt to run the makefile. The problem is I don't know how to link programs involving an external library (like glfw). I tried to specify the library path like:

`link /nologo /LIBPATH:"files\libs" main.obj sphere.obj`

This gives errors like "unresolved external symbols [glfw functions ex:glfwinit(),etc]". Specifying the library glfw3.lib with the .obj files like:

```
link /nologo /LIBPATH:"files\libs" main.obj sphere.obj glfw3.lib
```

again gives a list of errors specifying many unresolved external symbols and asks to use /NODEFAULTLIB which doesn't work either.
So how am I supposed to link these programs?

**EDIT:**
Also: I have 64 bit glfw3.lib . I used both the developer command prompt and the x64 native tools command prompt. With the developer command prompt I got an error:

```
LIBCMT.lib(std_type_info_static.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

So I used x64 native tools command prompt. The following errors are the errors I got using x64 native tools command prompt.
On specifying glfw3.lib along with the .obj files, I am getting these errors:

```
        link /nologo /LIBPATH:"..\SoC Other Files" glad.obj Planet.obj ImageLoader.obj Shader.obj Sphere.obj glfw3.lib
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(init.obj)' in function '_glfwInputError'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(window.obj)' in function 'glfwSetWindowAttrib'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)' in function 'glfwGetGamepadState'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(init.obj)' in function 'terminate'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(window.obj)' in function 'glfwSetWindowAttrib'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrt.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(init.obj)' in function 'vsnprintf'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrt.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj)' in function '_glfwCreateContextOSMesa'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj)' in function '_glfwGetVulkanResultString'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj)' in function 'choosePixelFormat'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(window.obj)' in function 'glfwWindowHintString'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_wassert' defined in 'libucrt.lib(assert.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_thread.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'strcspn' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strcspn.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)' in function 'glfwUpdateGamepadMappings'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'strncmp' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)' in function 'parseMapping'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'strncmp' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'strncmp' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'realloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(realloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)' in function 'glfwUpdateGamepadMappings'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'realloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(realloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'realloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(realloc.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'strtoul' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strtox.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)' in function 'parseMapping'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__stdio_common_vsscanf' defined in 'libucrt.lib(input.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(context.obj)' in function '_vsscanf_l'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'wcscmp' defined in 'libucrt.lib(wcscmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj)' in function '_glfwPollMonitorsWin32'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)' in function 'refreshVideoModes'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol 'qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol 'powf' defined in 'libucrt.lib(powf.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)' in function 'glfwSetGamma'
glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy referenced in function glfwWindowHintString
glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy
glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy
glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strspn referenced in function glfwUpdateGamepadMappings
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage referenced in function createHelperWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW referenced in function createHelperWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW referenced in function createHelperWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterDeviceNotificationW referenced in function createHelperWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_UnregisterDeviceNotification referenced in function _glfwPlatformTerminate
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW referenced in function createHelperWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformTerminate
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow referenced in function createHelperWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ToUnicode referenced in function _glfwUpdateKeyNamesWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW referenced in function _glfwUpdateKeyNamesWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW
glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SystemParametersInfoW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SystemParametersInfoW
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_wcscpy referenced in function createMonitor
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDCW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteDC referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceCaps referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC
glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChangeDisplaySettingsExW referenced in function _glfwSetVideoModeWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplaySettingsW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetVideoModes
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplaySettingsExW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplayDevicesW referenced in function _glfwPollMonitorsWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMonitorInfoW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetMonitorWorkarea
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMonitorInfoW
glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplayMonitors referenced in function createMonitor
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateBitmap referenced in function createIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateRectRgn referenced in function updateFramebufferTransparency
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteObject referenced in function createIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDIBSection referenced in function createIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TrackMouseEvent referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMessageTime referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SendMessageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PostMessageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WaitMessage referenced in function _glfwPlatformWaitEvents
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DefWindowProcW referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_UnregisterClassW referenced in function _glfwUnregisterWindowClassWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassExW referenced in function _glfwRegisterWindowClassWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetLayeredWindowAttributes referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowOpacity
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetLayeredWindowAttributes referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowOpacity
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_FlashWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformRequestWindowAttention
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MoveWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowPos referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowPos
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowPlacement referenced in function createNativeWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowPlacement referenced in function createNativeWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsWindowVisible referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowVisible
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsIconic referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowIconified
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_BringWindowToTop referenced in function _glfwPlatformFocusWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsZoomed referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowMaximized
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_OpenClipboard referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetClipboardString
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CloseClipboard referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetClipboardString
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetClipboardData referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetClipboardString
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClipboardData referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetClipboardString
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EmptyClipboard referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetClipboardString
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetFocus referenced in function _glfwPlatformFocusWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetActiveWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowFocused
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetKeyState referenced in function _glfwPlatformPollEvents
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCapture referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseCapture referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MsgWaitForMultipleObjects referenced in function _glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetSystemMetrics referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetForegroundWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformFocusWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RedrawWindow referenced in function updateFramebufferTransparency
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetPropW referenced in function createNativeWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetPropW referenced in function _glfwPlatformPollEvents
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RemovePropW referenced in function _glfwPlatformDestroyWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowTextW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClientRect referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowSize
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowRect referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_AdjustWindowRectEx referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowPos
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCursorPos referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetCursorPos
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCursor referenced in function updateCursorImage
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCursorPos referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetCursorPos
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ClientToScreen referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetCursorPos
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ScreenToClient referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetCursorPos
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WindowFromPoint referenced in function cursorInContentArea
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ClipCursor referenced in function updateClipRect
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetRect referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowFrameSize
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PtInRect referenced in function cursorInContentArea
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowLongW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowLongW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClassLongPtrW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadCursorW referenced in function _glfwRegisterWindowClassWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyIcon referenced in function _glfwPlatformDestroyCursor
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadImageW referenced in function _glfwRegisterWindowClassWin32
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateIconIndirect referenced in function createIcon
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MonitorFromWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowContentScale
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetRawInputData referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterRawInputDevices referenced in function enableRawMouseMotion
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragQueryFileW referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragQueryPoint referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragFinish referenced in function windowProc
glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragAcceptFiles referenced in function createNativeWindow
glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetRawInputDeviceInfoA referenced in function supportsXInput
glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetRawInputDeviceList referenced in function supportsXInput
glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChoosePixelFormat referenced in function _glfwInitWGL
glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DescribePixelFormat referenced in function _glfwCreateContextWGL
glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetPixelFormat referenced in function _glfwInitWGL
glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SwapBuffers referenced in function swapBuffersWGL
glad.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 100 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

This is the makefile:

```
INC = "..\Code Files\include"
INC_SH = "..\Code Files\Shader Class"
INC_SP = "..\Code Files\Sphere"
LOC = "..\SoC Other Files"

Planet.exe: glad.obj ImageLoader.obj Shader.obj Sphere.obj Planet.obj
    link /nologo /LIBPATH:$(LOC) glad.obj Planet.obj ImageLoader.obj Shader.obj Sphere.obj glfw3.lib
glad.obj: {../SoC Other Files}glad.c
    cl /c /nologo /I $(LOC) "../SoC Other Files/glad.c"
ImageLoader.obj: {../SoC Other Files}ImageLoader.cpp
    cl /c /nologo /I $(INC) /EHsc "../SoC Other Files/ImageLoader.cpp"
Shader.obj: {../Code Files/Shader Class}Shader.cpp
    cl /c /nologo /I $(INC) /EHsc "..\Code Files\Shader Class\Shader.cpp"
Sphere.obj: {../Code Files/Sphere}Sphere.cpp
    cl /c /nologo /I $(INC) /I $(INC_SH) /EHsc "../Code Files/Sphere/Sphere.cpp"
Planet.obj: {../Code Files/Main Code}Planet.cpp
    cl /c /nologo /I $(INC) /I $(INC_SH) /I $(INC_SP) /EHsc "../Code Files/Main Code/Planet.cpp"
```

Comment: `gives a list of errors` Please post that list. The reference to `/nodefaultlib` hints to a possible inconsistency between your compile settings and the libraries you are trying to link. Also post the `cl` command you are using to compile the obj files.

Comment: Btw, if you are able to build the project from the IDE you can find the "command line" under compile and link in the project settings. Or in the `.tlog` files under the build directory.

Comment: Basically what I want is an option to replace -lglfw (like we would have written in a makefile for linux). I am unable to find this on the internet.

Comment: The link errors indicate that you are trying to link to the debug build (i) of the DLL runtime (ii). Both (i) and (ii) should match between the objects you compile and the libraries you link to. If you are able to build from the IDE it would be easiest to borrow the command lines from there.

Comment: I am a beginner at using visual studio. Can you please help me out how should I get the command lines from the IDE? On searching for "command line" in the search box, it opens a empty developer command prompt.

Comment: Right click the project name in Solution Explorer, choose Properties. In the Configuration Properties on the left hand size, expand C/C++ and select Command Line under it. Repeat for Linker / Command Line.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dxiv!! That helped a lot!!